# Validating an input and populating options based on array/proc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a `User` model (incidentally, using Devise for this).

I've added a set of custom fields, some of which have quite a complex range of values (like employment status, industry, etc).

I'm trying to use a pre-defined set of values which I define in the `User` model, so that I can:

1. Populate edit screens with a pre-determined list of values
2. Validate the input submission to make sure that the option the user is selecting is an available option

Let's take my "gender" field setup and validation, for example. It's close, but I can't get it to work when I'm validating the second example here:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :gender,
            :inclusion => { :in => proc { |record| record.options_gender } }

  # Attempt 1: This doesn't work, but is what I need, because it defines both values to store, and also text strings to display.
  def options_gender
    [
        ['Male','male'],
        ['Female','female'],
        ['I\'d rather not say','nonspecific']
    ]
  end

  # Attempt 2: This does work for the validation, but doesn't let me define the corresponding text to display
  def options_gender
    ['male', 'female', 'nonspecific']
  end

end
```

My `options_gender` are also pulled into the edit form for users:

```
<%= f.input :gender, :collection => @user.options_gender, label: "Which gender do you identify as?" %>
```

Perhaps there's a way to either fix *Attempt 1* to correctly validate, or another technique I can use to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :gender, inclusion: { in: proc {|user| user.options_gender.keys }}

  def options_gender
    {'male'=>'Male', 'female'=>'Female', 'nonspecific'=>'I\'d rather not say'}
  end
end
```

and this

```
<%= f.input :gender, :collection => @user.options_gender.sort.map {|k,v| [v,k]}, label: "Which gender do you identify as?" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Unfortunately I get a ``method_missing': undefined local variable or method `options_gender' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NameError)` when I try it. Any ideas?

Comment: I updated/changed my answer. I think i have a better grasp on the problem now. try that

Comment: I was actually just working to get your previous answer to work, and managed to do that with this validation:

`validates :gender, :inclusion => { :in => proc { |record| record.options_gender.keys } }`

And in the view:

`f.input :gender, :collection => @user.options_gender.sort.map {|k,v| [v,k]}, label: "Which gender do you identify as?"`

Do you think your updated edit is a better approach to the problem? I guess it'd require duplicating many times, for each different field?

Comment: Hmm no probably not. I'll revert my answer back. Glad you were able to get it to work :)

Comment: Alright! Feel free to put that chunk into your answer and I'll mark as the solution anyway--you got me on the right track!